# Memory usage between 32-bit pool and 64-bit pool

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory-management, iis-7.5

We have an ASP.NET application, built around MonoRail and NHibernate, and I have noticed a strange behavior between if running it with 64-bit mode or 32-bit mode. Everything is compiled as AnyCPU, and runs fine with both modes, but the memory usage differs dramatically.

Look at the following snapshots from ANTS:

32bit_snapshot: [image]

vs

64bit_snapshot: [image]

The usage scenario for both snapshots are pretty much equivalent (I have hit the same pages on both runs).

Firstly, why is the Unused memory so high in 64-bit mode? And why would unmanaged memory be 4 times the size on 64-bit mode?

Any insight on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 15):

The initial memory allocation for a 64 bit process is much higher than it would be for an equivalent 32 bit process.

Theoretically this allows garbage collection to run much less often, which should increase performance. It also helps with fragmentation as larger memory blocks are allocated at a time.

This article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/64-bit-vs-32-bit/ gives a more detailed explanation.

The higher unmanaged memory usage you are seeing is probably due to the fact that .NET objects running in 32 bit mode use a minimum of 12 bytes (8 bytes + 4 byte reference) while the same object in 64 bit would take 24 bytes (12 bytes + 8 byte reference).

Another article to explain this more completely: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/object-overhead-the-hidden-.net-memory--allocation-cost/

Comment: Thank you for the article, that explains a lot. However, I still can't see the correlation for the unmanaged part of memory, this would still have been allocated by the unmanaged code and not CLR itself, no?

Comment: I would believe that if the difference was less than 100%, but it's 300% :/ Something else must be the cause for that.

Comment: Keep in mind that the above numbers are for a base, empty object. If the object has multiple properties, those numbers would go up exponentially so the expansion wouldn't necessarily be linear.

Comment: Still, a 100% increase would be the result of a fixed amount of empty objects which would have double the overhead, but not 300%?

Comment: If the objects are not empty though, and each contains multiple properties which get more data allocated to them than their 32 bit counterparts, then that could explain this. It would be impossible to know for sure though without getting into the memory profile details.

Comment: @jishi, do u know what is happening in your umanaged code? Maybe it just have memmory leaks? Besides, I think there could be allocated memmory for unmanaged code with great reserve, just analogically to you hosting application.

Comment: No, I don't have any insight on that. We don't have any unmanaged code ourselves, so it's from dependency libs. We haven't seen any indications of memory leaks in those, my main guess is that the memory is for NHibernate, and/or GDI (we do a lot of image resizing)

Comment: I awarded you the bounty since your answer was the most comprehensive. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3):

The standard answer to memory issues with 64-bit systems is that most memory operations by default are aligned to 16 bytes. Memory reads to/from 128-bit XXM registers are expected to align with 16-byte boundaries. Two parameters in a stack take the same amount of memory as three (return address takes the missing 8 bytes). Gnu malloc aligns allocated areas to 16 byte boundaries.

If the size of the allocated units is small, then the overhead will be huge: first the overhead from aligning the data and then there's the overhead of aligning the bookkeeping associated to the data.

Also I'd predict that in 64-bit systems the data structures have evolved: instead of binary, or 2-3-4, balanced, splay or whatever trees it possibly makes sense to have radix 16 trees that can have a lot of slack but can be processed fast with SSE extensions that are guaranteed to be there.

Comment: Most of the "data" that occupies memory in our application seems to be string[] objects. I'm sure that larger strings wont have difficulties allocating memory, and the overhead should then be a few bytes at the end of every string. That can hardly account for memory utilization several times the size of a 32-bit process?

Comment: @jishi: Can you give a histogram of the string lengths? (and no, I'm not an expert on .NET practices, but I have a vivid imagination!)

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you exacly what is going on, but probally do a good guess. A 32bit process has different memory limitations than the 64bit process. The CLR will run the GC often in the 32bit process. You can see this by the spikes on you graph. However when you are running the 64bit process the GC will not be called till you are getting low on memory. This will depend on you total memory usage of your system.

In numbers your 32bit process can only allocate around 1gig, and you 64bit can allocate all your memory. In the 32bit process the GC will start cleaning up sooner, because your program will suffer performance when it uses to much memory. The CLR on the 64bit process will start cleaning up when your total system memory drops below a certain trashhold.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, the difference in active memory is not that much and can somewhat be explained that it might not have garbage collected as much on the 64-bit run. But what I'm curious about is why it would think that it needs to allocate almost 1 GB of memory, when the application itself only uses about 200 MB? And the unmanaged memory, which isn't garbage collected, isn't explained by this.

Comment: You have probably a few gigs availible on your machine. The 64bit process gets a certain amount of the availble memory. If you have less memory availble the process will use/get less memory. Try to allocate the availible memory and the 64bit process will use less memory.